# Expo crashes with no Reason

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am having a project here, using Expo managed workflow. When I run it on my physical device, it just crashes and says 'Unfortunately Expo has stopped'. The crash occurs in the MapScreen.js file. I use ->

- react-native-maps
- expo-location
- react-native-maps-directions
- react-native-modal
- lottie-react-native
- react-native-router-flux
- firebase

The error comes when I click on the button (please find the code below) 
MapScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import {
  Button,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { Poppins_400Regular, useFonts } from "@expo-google-fonts/poppins";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import MapViewDirections from "react-native-maps-directions";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";
import { firebase } from "../functions/firebase";

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

const MapScreen = ({ longitude, latitude, searchResult }) => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Poppins_400Regular,
  });

  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [mapRegion, setmapRegion] = useState(null);
  const [customMark, setcustomMark] = useState(null);
  const [modal0Show, setmodal0Show] = useState(true);
  const [modal1Show, setmodal1Show] = useState(false);
  const [didAccept, setdidAccept] = useState(false);

  const apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
      }
      if (status === "granted") {
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setmapRegion({
          longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          latitude: location.coords.latitude,
          longitudeDelta: 3,
          latitudeDelta: 3,
        });
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRegion) {
      setcustomMark({ latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude });
    }
  }, [mapRegion]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (errorMsg) {
      console.log("err " + errorMsg);
    }
  }, [errorMsg]);

  function modalHideShow() {
    setmodal0Show(false);
    setmodal1Show(true);
    searchForDriver();
    searchForUpdates();
  }

  function searchForDriver() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("beforePick/")
      .set({
        searchForDriver: true,
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setErrorMsg(err);
      });
  }

  function searchForUpdates() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("beforePick/")
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.val().searchForDriver === false) {
          setmodal0Show(false);
          setdidAccept(true);
          setmodal1Show(false);
          Actions.push("lobby");
        }
      });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {fontsLoaded && (
        <View>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          {modal1Show === false && (
            <MapView initialRegion={mapRegion} style={styles.mapView}>
              {customMark && (
                <MapViewDirections
                  origin={{
                    latitude: mapRegion.latitude,
                    longitude: mapRegion.longitude,
                  }}
                  destination={{
                    latitude: customMark.latitude,
                    longitude: customMark.longitude,
                  }}
                  apikey={apikey}
                  strokeWidth={3}
                  strokeColor="hotpink"
                />
              )}
              {mapRegion && (
                <Marker coordinate={mapRegion} title="Me" description="Myself">
                  <Image
                    source={require("../images/155-1551908_open-google-current-location-icon.png")}
                    style={styles.currentLocationIcon}
                  />
                </Marker>
              )}
              {customMark && <Marker coordinate={customMark}></Marker>}
            </MapView>
          )}
          {modal0Show && (
            <View
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                top: deviceHeight - 100,
                height: "auto",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                width: "100%",
              }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.modalText0}>
                {searchResult.address_components[0].long_name}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.modalText1}>
                {searchResult.formatted_address}
              </Text>
              <Button
                title="Get Driver !"
                style={styles.modalButton0}
                onPress={modalHideShow}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      )}
      <View>
        {modal1Show === true && (
          <View>
            <Modal
              deviceHeight={deviceHeight}
              deviceWidth={deviceWidth}
              isVisible={modal1Show}
              backdropColor="#B4B3DB"
              backdropOpacity={0.8}
              animationIn="zoomInDown"
              animationOut="zoomOutUp"
              animationInTiming={600}
              animationOutTiming={600}
              backdropTransitionInTiming={600}
              backdropTransitionOutTiming={600}
            >
              <View style={styles.modal1Container1}>
                <LottieView
                  style={{
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                  }}
                  source={require("../images/14717-sedan-car-animation.json")}
                  autoPlay
                  loop
                />
                <Text>Looking for Driver...</Text>
              </View>
            </Modal>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here's the button part ->

```
{modal0Show && (
                <View
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: deviceHeight - 100,
                    height: "auto",
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    width: "100%",
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.modalText0}>
                    {searchResult.address_components[0].long_name}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.modalText1}>
                    {searchResult.formatted_address}
                  </Text>
                  <Button
                    title="Get Driver !"
                    style={styles.modalButton0}
                    onPress={modalHideShow}
                  />
                </View>
              )}
```

Any idea why this is coming ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue before and it was a part of my code that only worked on IOS and not Andriod that gave me the same error. Removing that portion of the code fixed it. I can't tell you exactly what is causing it, but id go over each part of the code checking what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem too and I found that when I set MapView initial latitude or longitude with none numeric value , Expo go will crash with no warning , and when I change initialize value to number , it work perfectly fine

in your code

```js
<MapView initialRegion={mapRegion} style={styles.mapView}>
              {customMark && (
                <MapViewDirections
                  origin={{
                    latitude: mapRegion.latitude,
                    longitude: mapRegion.longitude,
                  }}
                  destination={{
                    latitude: customMark.latitude,
                    longitude: customMark.longitude,
                  }}
                  apikey={apikey}
                  strokeWidth={3}
                  strokeColor="hotpink"
                />
```

MapView was set to undefine because you initialize mapRegion to null and was rendered before useEffect was run , maybe change initialize mapRegion.latitude and mapRegion.longitude to number might help